# Creating htaccess file For Redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I created a „.htaccess“ file to redirect the website visitors from an old page (example.com) to a new page (example.org). The challenge is that I want to redirect most old pages to a specific url address. As I read I can do it with the following code:

```
Redirect 301 /10parami.htm https://www.example.org/de/
```

This works fine for the more than 200 pages which I want to redirect. But to make sure that all other pages are also redirected to the new domain, I added the following code. If I add this code in the „.htaccess“ file, it redirects all my old pages to the starting page of the new domain. But this is not what I want. I want to redirect the more than 200 old pages to a specific page on the new domain. The problem is, when I combine the more than 200 redirects with the following code, you are always directed to the starting page of the new domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In the attachment I added the „.htaccess“ file. The more than 200 redirects work perfectly if I delete the addition code „RewriteEngine On …“. But I need to make sure that all other pages are also redirected to the new domain, so that I need the additional code.

Is anybody able to fix it?

my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
    Redirect 301 /prayong_accomodation_files/prayong_accomodation.htm https://www.example.org/plan-a-visit/
Redirect 301 /prayong_deutsch_files/watprayong-index.html https://www.example.org
Redirect 301 /selberueben_files/index.htm https://www.example.org
Redirect 301 /10parami.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /11benefits.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-11-benefits-of-practicing-metta/
Redirect 301 /16predictions.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-16-predictions-of-the-buddha-acharn-veeranon/
Redirect 301 /16upakilesa.htm https://www.example.org/blog/16-defilements-upakilesa/
Redirect 301 /16voraussagen.html https://www.example.org/de/die-sechzehn-vorhersagen-des-buddha-von-phra-khru-palat-veeranon-verananto/3338/
Redirect 301 /4autoritaeten.htm https://www.example.org/de/a-iv-180-die-vier-grossen-autoritaeten/3302/
Redirect 301 /4edlewahrheiten.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-vier-edlen-wahrheiten/3245/
Redirect 301 /4nobletruths.htm https://www.example.org/blog/heart-teachings-of-the-buddha-the-four-noble-truths/
Redirect 301 /5khanda_eng.htm https://www.example.org/blog/heart-teachings-of-the-buddha-five-aggregates-of-existence/
Redirect 301 /5recollectionschant.html https://www.example.org/blog/5-frequent-recollections/
Redirect 301 /5regeln.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-fuenf-buddhistischen-regeln/
Redirect 301 /8fachpfad.htm https://www.example.org/de/der-edle-achtfache-pfad/3261/
Redirect 301 /8foldpath.htm https://www.example.org/blog/heart-teachings-of-the-buddha-the-noble-eightfold-path/
Redirect 301 /8precepts.htm https://www.example.org/blog/buddhist-ethic-principles-the-eight-precepts/
Redirect 301 /8regeln.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-acht-buddhistischen-regeln/3257/
Redirect 301 /8regelnannahme.htm https://www.example.org/de/das-nehmen-der-acht-moralregeln/3259/
Redirect 301 /acaryabuddharakkhita-metta.html https://www.example.org/de/metta-meditation-von-acarya-buddharakkhita/3390/
Redirect 301 /acharn-mun.html https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-of-the-most-venerable-phra-acharn-mun-walking-meditation/
Redirect 301 /acharnphet-deutsch.html https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /acharnphet-english_17-31-34.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /acharnphet-english.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /acharnphet-index.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /activities.htm https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /aidstemple.htm https://www.example.org/donations/aids-temple-wat-phra-bat-nam-phu-lopburi/
Redirect 301 /akammaniya.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-akammaniya-numerical-sayings-anguttara-nikhaya/
Redirect 301 /aktivitaeten.htm https://www.example.org/de/vipassana-meditations-retreats-termine/
Redirect 301 /allgembuddhismus.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus-alles-was-man-wissen-sollte/
Redirect 301 /angulimala.htm https://www.example.org/de/angulimala-paritta/3315/
Redirect 301 /aplien-leben.htm https://www.example.org/de/kurzer-lebenslauf-von-phra-ajahn-plien-panyapatipo/3379/
Redirect 301 /aplien11resultate-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /aplien4brahmavihara-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-vier-goettlichen-verweilungszustaende-gleichmut-upekkha-von-phra-acharn-plien/3374/
Redirect 301 /aplienkaruna-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-vier-goettlichen-verweilungszustaende-karuna-oder-mitgefuehl-von-phra-acharn-plien/3370/
Redirect 301 /aplienmetta-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-vier-goettlichen-verweilungszustaende-freundlichkeit-metta-als-unterstuetzung-fuer-die-welt-von-phra-acharn-plien/3365/
Redirect 301 /aplienmudita-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-vier-goettlichen-verweilungszustaende-mitfreude-mudita-von-phra-acharn-plien/3372/
Redirect 301 /aplienupekkha-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-vier-goettlichen-verweilungszustaende-gleichmut-upekkha-von-phra-acharn-plien/3374/
Redirect 301 /arbeitsmeditation.html https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /asahalapuja.htm https://www.example.org/blog/buddhist-holidays-asahala-puja-day/
Redirect 301 /ballad.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-of-the-most-venerable-phra-acharn-mun-the-ballad-of-liberation-from-the-khandhas/
Redirect 301 /basic.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-the-basic-method-of-meditation-by-acharn-brahmavamso/
Redirect 301 /bewusstsein.htm https://www.example.org/de/bewusst-sein-anweisungen-von-acharn-sangwahn/3352/
Redirect 301 /biolpoo.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-biography-of-the-ven-phra-acharn-sangwahn-khemako/
Redirect 301 /bojjhanga.htm https://www.example.org/de/bojjhanga-die-sieben-erleuchtungsglieder/3300/
Redirect 301 /buddhadasa_index.html https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-of-ven-acharn-buddhadasa-bhikkhu-no-religion/
Redirect 301 /buddhaonpain.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-dealing-with-pain-samyutta-nikhaya/
Redirect 301 /buddharakmetta-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/metta-meditation-von-acarya-buddharakkhita/3390/
Redirect 301 /buddhism.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /buddhway.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-buddhist-way-ven-acharn-lee/
Redirect 301 /chantindex.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /chanting.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /childprotection-index.html https://www.example.org/donations/gurudakshina-the-practice-of-giving-back/
Redirect 301 /childprotection.html https://www.example.org/donations/gurudakshina-the-practice-of-giving-back/
Redirect 301 /compassionayya.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-loving-kindness-meditation-compassion-a-guided-meditation-by-ven-ayya-khema/
Redirect 301 /concentration.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-experiencing-concentration-by-acharn-sanong-katapunyo/
Redirect 301 /contact.htm https://www.example.org/contact/
Redirect 301 /dailysati.htm https://www.example.org/blog/mindfulness-in-daily-life/
Redirect 301 /dailyteaching.htm https://www.example.org/vipassana-retreat-thailand/
Redirect 301 /dana_deutsch.htm https://www.example.org/de/dana/3294/
Redirect 301 /dealpain.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-using-meditation-to-deal-with-pain-illness-and-death-by-thanissaro-bhikkhu/
Redirect 301 /december12-pic_index.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /deciding.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-deciding-to-become-a-nun/
Redirect 301 /deredle-unedle.htm https://www.example.org/de/a-iv-180-die-vier-grossen-autoritaeten-2/3304/
Redirect 301 /deutsch-index.html https://www.example.org/de
Redirect 301 /deutschindex.htm https://www.example.org/de
Redirect 301 /dhammamtvh.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-dhamma-talk-given-during-a-retreat-by-ven-mettavihari-bhikkhu/
Redirect 301 /dhammaotherlanguages.html https://www.example.org/
Redirect 301 /dhammapada.htm https://www.example.org/blog/dhammapada-the-path-of-virtue/
Redirect 301 /dhammateachings.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /dhutanga.htm https://www.example.org/blog/sangha-what-is-dhutanga-practice/
Redirect 301 /dhutangadeutsch.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /download_deutsch.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /download_english.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /downloads.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /dreamsource.htm https://www.example.org/blog/sangha-four-sources-of-dreams/
Redirect 301 /einfuehrung.htm https://www.example.org/de/einfuehrung-in-die-meditation-von-brigitte-schrottenbacher/3396/
Redirect 301 /einstein.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /emotionen.htm https://www.example.org/de/das-entwickeln-von-rechter-konzentration-in-der-meditation-belehrung-vom-ehrwuerdigen-phra-acharn-putt/3342/
Redirect 301 /english-index.html https://www.example.org/
Redirect 301 /englishindex.htm https://www.example.org/
Redirect 301 /erklaerungen.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /eveningchant.htm https://www.example.org/blog/evening-chanting-usual-version-in-other-temples/
Redirect 301 /events.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /feiertage.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-drei-buddhistischen-feiertage/3306/
Redirect 301 /flood-details.html https://www.example.org/donations/monthly-support-for-nuns-in-thailand-and-bhutan/
Redirect 301 /flood-index.html https://www.example.org/donations/monthly-support-for-nuns-in-thailand-and-bhutan/
Redirect 301 /flut-abrechnung.html https://www.example.org/de/donations/thailand-flut-hilfe-projekt-2011/
Redirect 301 /fuenfgruppen.htm https://www.example.org/de/die-fuenf-gruppen-des-anhaftens-pancakkhandho/3263/
Redirect 301 /gallery_index.htm https://www.example.org/vipassana-retreat-thailand/
Redirect 301 /happycouple.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-how-to-live-a-happy-couple-life-acharn-veeranon/
Redirect 301 /helpnepal.html https://www.example.org/donations/keeping-the-ancient-buddhist-library/
Redirect 301 /impressum.htm https://www.example.org/contact/
Redirect 301 /index.html https://www.example.org/
Redirect 301 /index_info.htm https://www.example.org/
Redirect 301 /info_index.htm https://www.example.org/
Redirect 301 /kalamasutta.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-kalama-sutta/
Redirect 301 /karma_index.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /keinereligion.htm https://www.example.org/de/keine-religion-von-buddhadasa-bhikkhu/
Redirect 301 /keyliber.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-key-to-liberation-ven-phra-acharn-chah/
Redirect 301 /kinderschutzprojekt.html https://www.example.org/de/donations/medikamentenspende-des-oesterreichischen-roten-kreuzes-fuer-beduerftige-in-thailand-projekt-ist-abgeschlossen/
Redirect 301 /knowletgo.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-know-and-let-go-ven-phra-acharn-sangwahn-khemako/
Redirect 301 /konten.html https://www.example.org/donation-programs/
Redirect 301 /konzentrationerleben.htm https://www.example.org/de/konzentration-erleben-von-acharn-sanong-katapunyo/3388/
Redirect 301 /lehrreden.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /leichterkoerper.htm https://www.example.org/de/leichter-koerper-leichter-geist-anleitung-zur-meditation-vom-ehrwuerdigen-phra-acharn-sangwahn-khemmako/3350/
Redirect 301 /letztepruefung.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /liebenyanaponika-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/liebe-metta-von-nyanaponika-mahathera-gekuerzte-fassungddd/3409/
Redirect 301 /lifeteachingbuddhadasa.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /link-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /link-d.html https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /linkenglish.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /linkenglish.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /loykrathong.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /lpootuad_engl.html https://www.example.org/blog/teaching-of-ven-luang-poo-tuad/
Redirect 301 /lpsim.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-words-of-the-most-venerable-luang-por-sim-bhikkhu/
Redirect 301 /maechee_index.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte/
Redirect 301 /makeupyourmind.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-make-up-your-mind-acharn-tippakorn/
Redirect 301 /makhapuja.htm https://www.example.org/blog/buddhist-holidays-makhapuja-day/
Redirect 301 /map-index.html https://www.example.org/plan-a-visit/
Redirect 301 /mapprayong.htm https://www.example.org/plan-a-visit/
Redirect 301 /mcbrigitte.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte/
Redirect 301 /mcbrigitte_indexdeutsch.html https://www.example.org/de/mc-brigitte/
Redirect 301 /meditationvideo.htm https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /meinleben.htm https://www.example.org/de/mc-brigitte-entscheidung-nonne-zu-werden/
Redirect 301 /metta-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/metta-sutta/3318/
Redirect 301 /mettachant.htm https://www.example.org/blog/metta/
Redirect 301 /mettakreise.htm https://www.example.org/de/metta-meditation-in-5-abschnitten-mettakreise/3381/
Redirect 301 /mettasutta-d.htm https://www.example.org/de/metta-sutta-sutta-der-allguete-von-sri-gnanawimala-maha-thero-auszug-aus-das-licht-der-lehre/3392/
Redirect 301 /mitbringen.html https://www.example.org/de/planung-vipassana-meditations-retreats/
Redirect 301 /monatskurse.html https://www.example.org/de/vipassana-meditations-retreat-in-thailand/
Redirect 301 /monthly-retreats.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /monthly-schedule.html https://www.example.org/vipassana-retreat-thailand/
Redirect 301 /morningchant.htm https://www.example.org/blog/morning-chanting-usual-version-in-other-temples/
Redirect 301 /mylife.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-my-life-as-a-buddhist-nun/
Redirect 301 /neujahrskurs_deutsch.html https://www.example.org/de/vipassana-meditations-retreats-termine/
Redirect 301 /news.html https://www.example.org/blog-classic-2-columns/
Redirect 301 /newyearchant.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /newyearsretreat_english.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /newyearsretreat_index.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /nibbana.htm https://www.example.org/de/nibbana-die-beschreibung-des-unbeschreiblichen/
Redirect 301 /noreligion.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-of-ven-acharn-buddhadasa-bhikkhu-no-religion/
Redirect 301 /noretreats.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /noteaching.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /noticingsumedho.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-noticing-space-by-acharn-sumedho/
Redirect 301 /originalface.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /ourmindisnofriend.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /ourmindisnotourfriend.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /overviewmetta.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-overview-of-loving-kindness-meditation/
Redirect 301 /P1_Dana_.htm https://www.example.org/de/der-weg-der-paramita/3265/
Redirect 301 /pancakammatthana.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-panca-kammatthana-ven-phra-acharn-sangwahn-khemako/
Redirect 301 /Parami_adhitthana.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-panca-kammatthana-ven-phra-acharn-sangwahn-khemako/
Redirect 301 /Parami_khanti.htm https://www.example.org/de/khanti-parami/3276/
Redirect 301 /Parami_metta.htm https://www.example.org/de/metta-parami/3282/
Redirect 301 /Parami_nekkhamma.htm https://www.example.org/de/nekkhamma-parami/3269/
Redirect 301 /Parami_panna.htm https://www.example.org/de/panna-parami/3272/
Redirect 301 /Parami_sacca.htm https://www.example.org/de/sacca-parami/3278/
Redirect 301 /Parami_sila.htm https://www.example.org/de/sila-parami/3267/
Redirect 301 /Parami_upekkha.htm https://www.example.org/de/upekkha-parami/3286/
Redirect 301 /Parami_viriya.htm https://www.example.org/de/viriya-parami/3274/
Redirect 301 /Paramita_Weg.htm https://www.example.org/de/der-weg-der-paramita/3265/
Redirect 301 /paticcasamuppada.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-paticcasamuppada-dependent-origination/
Redirect 301 /pavarana.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /pic_socialproject.htm https://www.example.org/donation-programs/
Redirect 301 /pics-floodrelief.html https://www.example.org/donations/monthly-support-for-nuns-in-thailand-and-bhutan/
Redirect 301 /picsfeb17.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /practising.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-practicing-insight-on-your-own-teachings-by-ven-acharn-thawee-baladhammo/
Redirect 301 /prayong_accomodation.htm https://www.example.org/plan-a-visit/
Redirect 301 /prayong_beschreibung.htm https://www.example.org/de/tempel-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /prayong_dailyschedule.htm https://www.example.org/vipassana-retreat-thailand/
Redirect 301 /prayong_deutsch.htm https://www.example.org/de/tempel-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /prayong_english.htm https://www.example.org/temple-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /prayong_gallery.htm https://www.example.org/de/tempel-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /prayong_lehrmethode.htm https://www.example.org/de/vipassana-meditations-retreat-in-thailand/
Redirect 301 /prayong_location.htm https://www.example.org/temple-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /prayong_method.htm https://www.example.org/vipassana-retreat-thailand/
Redirect 301 /prayong_tagesablauf.htm https://www.example.org/de/tempel-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /prayong_unterkunft.htm https://www.example.org/de/tempel-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /py-directions.html https://www.example.org/temple-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /py-directions_eng.html https://www.example.org/temple-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /py-directionsthai.html https://www.example.org/de/tempel-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /py-eveningchant.html https://www.example.org/blog/evening-chanting-usual-version-in-other-temples/
Redirect 301 /py-map-routeeng.html https://www.example.org/de/tempel-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /py-morningchant.html https://www.example.org/blog/morning-chanting-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /pydeutsch_index.html https://www.example.org/de/planung-vipassana-meditations-retreats/
Redirect 301 /raphael-english.html https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /raum.htm https://www.example.org/de/das-wahrnehmen-von-raum-von-acharn-sumedho/3383/
Redirect 301 /realhome.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-our-real-home-ven-phra-acharn-chah/
Redirect 301 /realworld_index.html https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /recollection.htm https://www.example.org/blog/recollection-of-the-32-parts-of-the-body/
Redirect 301 /reinheit.htm https://www.example.org/de/reinheit-und-klarblick-von-acharn-thawee-baladhammo/3336/
Redirect 301 /relief.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-relief-of-suffering-ven-acharn-lee/
Redirect 301 /retreats.html https://www.example.org/events/
Redirect 301 /rose.htm https://www.example.org/de/eine-rose-zum-anstecken-nach-thich-nhat-hanhs-a-rose-for-your-pocket/3394/
Redirect 301 /satipatthana.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-satipatthana-vipassana-by-venerable-mahasi-sayadaw/
Redirect 301 /seeing.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-seeing-the-mind-by-ven-luang-por-putt/
Redirect 301 /selberueben.htm https://www.example.org/de/selber-klarblick-ueben-ein-leitfaden-fuer-achtsamkeit-von-phra-acharn-thawie-baladhammo/3325/
Redirect 301 /shortinstruction.htm https://www.example.org/blog/a-short-meditation-instruction/
Redirect 301 /soc-medizin.html https://www.example.org/de/donations/medikamentenspende-des-oesterreichischen-roten-kreuzes-fuer-beduerftige-in-thailand-projekt-ist-abgeschlossen/
Redirect 301 /soc-pic-index.html https://www.example.org/de/soziale-projekte/
Redirect 301 /socialproject-acnr.html https://www.example.org/donation-programs/
Redirect 301 /socialprojects.htm https://www.example.org/donation-programs/
Redirect 301 /socialprojects_index.htm https://www.example.org/donation-programs/
Redirect 301 /sozial-medikamente.html https://www.example.org/de/donations/medikamentenspende-des-oesterreichischen-roten-kreuzes-fuer-beduerftige-in-thailand-projekt-ist-abgeschlossen/
Redirect 301 /sozialeprojekte.htm https://www.example.org/de/soziale-projekte/
Redirect 301 /thefiveprecepts.htm https://www.example.org/blog/buddhist-ethic-principles-explaining-the-five-precepts/
Redirect 301 /tilakkhana.htm https://www.example.org/blog/heart-teachings-of-the-buddha-ti-lakkhana-three-characteristics-of-existence/
Redirect 301 /tobring.html https://www.example.org/plan-a-visit/
Redirect 301 /tucco.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-tucco-pothila-ven-phra-acharn-chah/
Redirect 301 /ultimatetest.htm https://www.example.org/mc-brigitte-buddhist-teachings/
Redirect 301 /utteranceslpoo.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-utterances-of-the-ven-phra-acharn-sangwahn-khemako/
Redirect 301 /values.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-human-values-ven-acharn-lee/
Redirect 301 /velama.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-velama-sutta-anguttara-nikhaya/
Redirect 301 /venchah.html https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-key-to-liberation-ven-phra-acharn-chah/
Redirect 301 /venchob.htm https://www.example.org/blog/the-story-of-venerable-acharn-chob/
Redirect 301 /venlee.html https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-buddhist-way-ven-acharn-lee/
Redirect 301 /vensangwahn.html https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-know-and-let-go-ven-phra-acharn-sangwahn-khemako/
Redirect 301 /ventip.html https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-make-up-your-mind-acharn-tippakorn/
Redirect 301 /venveeranon.html https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-16-predictions-of-the-buddha-acharn-veeranon/
Redirect 301 /vesak.htm https://www.example.org/blog/buddhist-holidays-vesak-day/
Redirect 301 /videos.html https://www.example.org/de/buddhismus/
Redirect 301 /vipassanamtvhri.htm https://www.example.org/de/vipassana-meditation-vom-ehrwuerdigen-phra-kru-kraisavilasa-metthavihari/3340/
Redirect 301 /wahreszhause.htm https://www.example.org/de/unser-wahres-zuhause-eine-lehrrede-gegeben-am-sterbebett-einer-laienanhaengerin-von-acharn-chah/3348/
Redirect 301 /walking-amun.html https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-of-the-most-venerable-phra-acharn-mun-walking-meditation/
Redirect 301 /watprayong-deutsch.html https://www.example.org/de/tempel-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /watprayong-english.html https://www.example.org/temple-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /watprayong-french.html https://www.example.org/temple-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /watprayong-index.html https://www.example.org/temple-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /watprayong_english.html https://www.example.org/temple-wat-prayong/
Redirect 301 /whatismeditation.htm https://www.example.org/blog/teachings-what-is-meditation-acharn-tippakorn/
Redirect 301 /wissenloslassen.htm https://www.example.org/de/wissen-und-loslassen-lehrreden-von-phra-acharn-sangwahn/3363/
```

Comment: What happens if you put your redirects to the top of your file? In theory that should redirect the user and if no redirect matched, the URL rewrite should send the user to the new domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

These mod_rewrite directives are processed first, regardless of whether you put them before or after your `Redirect` directives. `Redirect` belongs to mod_alias and so are processed independently.

The above `RewriteRule` also redirects to the same URL-path on the target domain. eg. `example.com/<foo>` to `example.org/<foo>`. However, you stated that you wanted to redirect to "to a specific URL". For this you will need to use a `RedirectMatch` directive (also part of mod_alias).

1. Delete the mod_rewrite directives above.
2. Add a single `RedirectMatch` *after* all your `Redirect` directives:

   ```
   RedirectMatch 301 ^/ https://www.example.org/<specific-url>
   ```

   All other URLs, that don't match the `Redirect` directives that precede it will be redirected to the specific URL as stated.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.